# How to transfer data from SQL Server to mongodb (using mongoose schema for validation)

Tags: sql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-migration

**Goal**
We have a MEAN stack application that implements a strict mongoose schema. The MEAN stack app needs to be seeded with data that originates from a SQL Server database. The app should function as expected as long as the seeded data complies with the mongoose schema.

**Problem**
Currently, the data transfer job is being done through the mongo CLI which does not perform validation. Issues that have come up have been Date objects being saved as strings, missing keys that are required on our schema, entire  documents missing, etc. The dev team has lost hours of development time debugging the app and discovering these data issues.

**Solution we are looking for**

How can we validate data so it:

- Throws errors
- Fails and halts the transfer
- Or gives some other indication that the data is not clean

**Disclaimer**
I was not part of the data transfer process so I don't have more detail on the specifics of that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general problem of what you might call "batch import", "extract-transform-load (ETL)", or "data store migration", disconnected from any particular tech. I'd approach it by:

1. Export the data into some portable format (e.g. CSV or JSON)
2. Push the data into the new system through the same validation logic that will handle new data on an ongoing basis.

It's often necessary to modify that logic a bit. For example, maybe your API will autogenerate time stamps for normal operation, but for data import, you want to explicitly set them from the old data source. A more complicated situation would be when there are constraints that cross your models/entities that need to be suspended until all the data is present.

Typically, you write your import script or system to generate a summary of how many records were processed, which ones failed, and why. Then you fix the issues, run it on those remaining records. Repeat until you're happy.

P.S. It's a good idea to version control your import script.

Answer (score 0):

Export to csv and write a small script using node. that will solve your problem. You   can use **fast-csv npm**